# How to interact with an OpenThread device?

Tags: texas-instruments, openthread

To preface this I have literally no idea what I am doing and I am just working it out as I go along.

I have just installed OpenThread onto a TI CC2538, but cannot for the life of me figure out if it is working.

The README.md file on the GitHub repository has this at the bottom, suggesting that I should be able to connect to it with a terminal session of some sort and from there I should be able to run all of the necessary commands.

> Open terminal to `/dev/ttyUSB1` (serial port settings: 115200 8-N-1).

However, I checked under `/dev` and there is no USB device mounted there.

To connect the CC2538 to my PC I have:

- A Segger J-Link EDU (connects to the 20 pin JTAG port)
- A micro USB cable

I don't know if anyone else has set something like this up and is able to point me in the right direction, but any help at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the SmartRF06, the serial port is presented via the TI XDS100v3 Emulator.  The XDS is based on an FTDI chip and new Linux kernels provide very good support for FTDI chips. If the kernel module does not kick in automatically, perform the following steps:

Connect the SmartRF to the linux box. Find the device's VID and PID (0403:a6d1 in the output below):

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0403:a6d1 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd
...
```

As root or with sudo, run the command below (if necessary, replace the vendor and product arguments with the values you got from lsusb):

```
modprobe ftdi_sio vendor=0x403 product=0xa6d1
```

From Kernel 3.12 run the command below:

```
modprobe ftdi_sio
echo 0403 a6d1 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/ftdi_sio/new_id
```

You may have have to remove package `brltty`, if it's installed.

The board should have enumerated as `/dev/ttyUSB{0,1}`. `ttyUSB1` will be the UART backchannel.

Comment: Thanks, so I had no idea what Kernel 3.12 was or how to access it, but I managed to chmod of new_id and edit it that way. This seems to work and ttyUSB0 and ttyUSB1 now show up, I am however having some issues: 1. If I restart my machine I have to do this all over again, and 2. I'm not really sure how to connect to the device, putty wont do anything when I click open (no feedback at all) so I tried cu using `cu -l /dev/ttyUSB1 -s 115200` however I get the following error `cu: open (/dev/ttyUSB1): Permission denied` followed by `cu: /dev/ttyUSB1: Line in use`